# Angular 12 migration to angular 13 with Angular Material version (12.2.13) does not match

Tags: angular, angular-material

i've a problem with material version :

*The Angular Material version (12.2.13) does not match the Angular CDK version (13.3.5).
Please ensure the versions of these two packages exactly match.*

when i resolv this with a "@angular/material": "^13.2.6", several problems occur... tslint, polyfill etc...

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.5",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.6",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.6",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^5.0.1",
    "keycloak-js": "^12.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^4.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tinymce": "^5.9.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
```

help me please.

Comment: have you tried changing the version of `@angular/material` (and supdependencies) to version `13.x.x` and deleting the `node_modules`-folder afterwards? To reinstall with npm/yarn?

Comment: hi, yes i changing @angular/material version to 13.3.4 with deleting node_module, and i reinstall all with npm install --force... i have other problem with tslint and polyfill and 
several issues with project files, 

but when i use :  "@angular/material": "^12.2.6", "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^12.2.6",

and i build:prod no problem in console...

Comment: Yeah `@angular/material` version 12 won't work with `@angular` version 13. If you really want to upgrade you have to consider fixing those errors somehow